# Parent() does not work because of <form>

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the parent() of this

```
<div id="acContentBox10" class="acContentBox">
```

When I make a console.log - Its undefined.

```
<div class="accordionContent" id="accordionContent4" style="display: block;">
<form action="" method="post" name="form" id="form25">
<div id="acContentBox4" class="acContentBox"> some code
<div id="acChildBox1" class="acChildBox" style="float:left"> some code
<div class="acBabyBox" id="acBabyBox8"> some code
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

If I remove the `<form>` it works great. But I need the form.

I just updated the code and added some of the jquery:

```
        var flex0 = $(this);
        var flex1 = $(this).parent('div'); 
        var flex2 = $(flex1).parent('div'); 
        var flex3 = $(flex2).parent('div'); // Shoud be "accordionContent4"
```

I am adding `.attr('id');` later in the Jquery.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is  "="" on line 1 ?

Comment: where is the script..?

Comment: Where is your jquery code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working NEW Fiddle => [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2DEV/3/)

"="" on line 1 should  be deleted

html:

```
<div class="accordionContent" id="accordionContent10"  style="display: block;">
<form action="" method="post" name="form" id="form25"> 
<div id="acContentBox10" class="acContentBox">some code
<div id="acChildBox1" class="acChildBox" style="float:left">some code
<div class="acBabyBox&quot;" id="acBabyBox20">Some code
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

script:

```
var idOfParent=$("#acContentBox10").parent().closest('div').attr("id");
alert(idOfParent);
```

Comment: I want to get the parent of the <div> Now I am getting the id of the form

Comment: Thanks. It work be using .parent().closest('div') instead of .parent('div')

Answer (score 0):

You would find parent using this:

```
var parent=$('#acContentBox10').parent();
```

Then you can do what you want to do with `parent` object.

And if you want to skip immediate parent and find some specific parent above that then you can use:

```
$('#acContentBox10').parent().find('#accordionContent10');
```

Comment: I need to get all the parents one by one. But the <form> block it. That why i use "div" in the parent like this -> .parent("div")

Comment: You can not be always sure that Outer parent will have specific "#accordionContent10" id .It may also be dynamic.Then what?